# Embed VBA in SSRS appear in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Is there anyway for me to add in a VBA code that would take effect, when the SSRS report is exported into excel. I have a report (main report) with 4 (sub reports). All reports are in portrait, except for one. I would like to know if SSRS supports the VBAs from SSRS to Excel. Would this work? Essentially that VBA would automatically change the orientation for 1 of the excel sheet from Portrait to Landscape.

Comment: It is not possible using SSRS. For the requeriment you mention I'd create an Excel template with all VBA code needed, then use SSIS - C# to inject the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much as well, but needed to confirm.